# Nusoap with wsdl issue with https

Tags: php, wsdl, nusoap

I want call a wsdl with https using nusoap, but this wsdl is https and use xsd with https, when i call wsdl with php using nusoap i can't import xsd because nusoap call xsd with http with port 80. How can resolve? Thanks!!

Comment: why dont u try php native soap client i dint had succes with nusoap also so i went  wit php one can u show what have u tried

Comment: I suggest you check the relevant source code in NuSOAP to see how it handles this. That's what I would do in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have make a simple solution have edited nusoap library to force at use protocol https, but i think that is a simple solution. :)